# Обозначение времени

Tags: пунктуация

Добрый день! Допускается ли обозначение времени (18.00 часов) в таком формате? Знаю, что 18.00 и 18. часов 00 минут предпочтительнее. Но! Допускается ли? Ошибка? Мой вопрос об обозначении времени

Comment: 18. часов 00 минут не предпочтительнее. Точку внутри предложения трудно обосновать, если вообще возможно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы не было путаницы c западной нормой, где точка внутри числительного ставится после тысяч единиц (10.000 m), после целых (18.00 £), верная традиция предписывает употреблять двоеточие — 18:00, где обозначение времени суток становится отличным от метрического. Такую запись можно продолжить и указанием секунд — 18:00:00.

Comment: Тысячи у них запятой разделяются.

Comment: @Alex_ander не совсем так: https://www.englishforums.com/English/10000Vs10000/bhllql/post.htm или https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10,000. То есть вы так же правы, как и shampar.